# I can not understand "uninitialized constant" in ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I have two files in folder *pc* under my home directory.

First file:

```
 class A
  class << self
   protected
    def foo
      puts "In foo"
     end
   end
 end
```

Second file:

```
  class B < A
   def bar
    self.class.class_eval { foo }
   end
  end

 B.new.bar
```

My problem is when I run the second file I get the following error:

```
  second.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant A (NameError)
```

Why is that?

Comment: You need to require the file that contains the class `A`.

Comment: Thanks @PNY for the quick response.Did you mean something like bellow?
require 'A.rb'

Comment: yes whatever the first file's name is. If `require` doesn't work, try `require_relative`

Comment: also it would be easier for everyone to know what are your file names exactly.

Comment: #class_a.rb

containg class A and 


#class_b.rb


containing class B.I did both require and require_relative but same error is happening .thnaks

Comment: yey solved finally by using using require_relative thnaks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `require_relative 'class_a'` or `require class_a`.

Note that the file's extension is not included.

Answer (score 2):

```
B.new.bar
# => In foo
```

just works fine in my console. I guess you probably forgot to require the file containing `A` from the file `B`.

In file `B` use

```
require 'a'
```

(assuming the file containing `A` is called `a.rb`).

I read the various comments, and just to avoid confusion, here's the full content of the two files.

**class_a.rb**

```
class A
  class << self
    protected
    def foo
      puts "In foo"
    end
  end
end
```

**class_b.rb**

```
require_relative 'class_a'

class B < A
  def bar
   self.class.class_eval { foo }
  end
end

puts B.new.bar
```

And here's how to execute them from the console

```
$ ruby class_b.rb 
In foo
```

Of course, you should execute the file `class_b.rb`, not `class_a.rb` or you will not see any result.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming it's all in the same file. If not, you'll need to `require` the first file into the next:

```
# class_b.rb
require 'class_a.rb'

class B < A
  def bar
    self.class.class_eval { foo }
  end
end

B.new.bar
#=> "In foo"
```

**UPDATE**:

In order to require the file, you may need to cite the path of the file relative to your current directory. For instance, if `class_a.rb` is located in `~/home` and you're running irb (or `class_b.rb` is in `~/home`), then you'd include `class_a.rb` by citing its relative path as follows:

```
require './class_a'
```

Comment: thanks @zeantsoi.I renamed my ruby file name and wrote require 'class_a.rb' like you said 
then i got the following error

       ruby-1.9.3-               p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- class_a.rb (LoadError)

I can't understand why this is happening

Comment: You need to include the path of the file relative to your current directory. I've updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: ahh problem is solved by using require_relative class_a.rb
any way thanks for your help